# SDL2 file not found

Tags: makefile, sdl-2

I downloaded SDL2 and used this command g++ -Isrc/include -Lsrc/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -LSDL2main -LSDL2 but when I use the make command it tells me that the SDL2 is not a file or directory.

I included all the SDL2 files in src.

I am using windows powershell and cmd.

I tried changing the command and downloading different SDL2 files.

Comment: Please paste the exact error message, and your directory structure.

Comment: To add to HolyBlackCat's message: please (a) use proper formatting as a code block, rather than normal text, (b) include the exact complete command line, and (c) the exact complete error message, using cut and paste from your actual terminal, not retyping by hand and not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

i actually fixed it but encountered a problem with the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SDL2/SDL2.h>

#include<clocale>

#include<msdelta.h>

#include "theplayer.h"

#include "hole.h"

#include "enemy.h"

using namespace std;

bool run = true;

SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);



double oldtime = 0;

double deltatime = clock() - oldtime;

double fps = (1.0 / deltatime) * 1000;

float speed = 10.0f;

void drawscreen(theplayer)
{

    theplayer theplayer;

    // render section
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    // draw things
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &theplayer.posrect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
void input(theplayer)
{
    theplayer theplayer;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            run = false;
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w)
            {
                theplayer.ypos -= speed ;
            }
            if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_s)
            {
                theplayer.ypos += speed;
                cout << theplayer.ypos;
            }
        }
    }
    theplayer.posrect.y = theplayer.ypos;
}
void update(theplayer, enemy, hole)
{
    theplayer theplayer;
    deltatime = clock() - oldtime;
    fps = (1.0 / deltatime) * 1000;
    oldtime = clock();
    input(theplayer);
    drawscreen(theplayer);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);


    theplayer theplayer;
    hole hole;
    enemy enemy;
    long long moves = 0, prev_moves = 0;
    while (run)
    {
        update(theplayer, enemy, hole);
    }



    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the theplayer.ypos is not updating

Comment: This is the answer section. It’s not the right place to ask a question.